# PHP header redirect not working when posting a form - using output buffer - but does in other cases?

Tags: php, forms, post, header

I have an unusual problem, only happening on one server.
Following code

```
....
elseif ($_GET['action']=='login') {

 if (empty($_POST['login_name'])) { $_POST['login_name']=''; }
 if (empty($_POST['login_pass'])) { $_POST['login_pass']=''; }
 if (!empty($_POST['send'])) {
  if (($_POST['login_name']==_ADMIN_NAME) and    ($_POST['login_pass']==_ADMIN_PASS)) {
   //Successfully logged in
   $_SESSION['logged']=1;

// DOES NOT WORK
   header('Location: '.$filename);
   die('Command '.$filename);
  }
 }
// Show Form;
include('plogin.inc.php');
} 
elseif ($_GET['action']=='logout') {
 $_SESSION['logged']=-1;
// DOES WORK!
 header('Location: '.$filename);
}
```

So the problem is this if i click the link logout, all goes well and i get redirected to $filename.
If i submit the login form it checks if the post is correct, set's the session var, but then dies instead of redirecting.

I got output buffers on, all error reporting but (no errors), it doesn't redirect when I post with the form even though it definitely passes (because the session var is set and I get to the die part)

What could be the cause for this behavior?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I, also, found redirect don't work sometimes after POST request. It is a browser not server-side problem, I think.

I use something like this:

```
if( sizeof( $_POST ) == 0 ) header( "Location: " . $url );
else echo '<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=' . $url . '"/></head><body>Redirecting to ' . $url . '</body></html>'
```

In short, if it is a POST request - then I use html refresh redirect, else - normal header redirect.

Comment: hey greate, someone who believes me that it has to do with the POST :) however this is really just happening on one server, not the other. but for now I will use your fix

Answer (score 2):

Did you test that a) the code is reached and b) the error reporting really is in effect?

```
//Successfully logged in
$_SESSION['logged']=1;

// code reached, error_reporting test
echo 'debug: would send location header', $filename, $unsetVariableTriggeringWarning;
flush();

if (headers_sent()) {
  die('cannot send location header (anymore)');
}
else {
  header('Location: '.$filename);
  die();
}
```

Comment: got this "would send location header Notice: Undefined variable: unsetVariableTriggeringWarning in /var/kunden/webs/***/pbook.inc.php on line 250" BUT did not get the info saying "cannot send location header (anymore)"

Comment: Even with flush()? Is there still some ob_xyz()-buffer active? echo 'ob_level: ', ob_get_level(); can tell.  
Did you use the echo 'debug: would send location header', $filename, $unset... version? I've edited that in later.

Comment: i know the filename is set and correct, as said before the header redirect is exactly the same for login and logout. the only difference is that one is just accessed via link and the other via form submission. i have   error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: And what about echo 'ob_level: ', ob_get_level();</i> ?  
I would place it directly before if(headers_Sent()) for testing

Answer (score 1):

might be a simple thing. The header() function does set a header, but does not terminate a script so that the header is sent immidiately after calling header().

You need to make php send the script result to the client. As you use output buffering, this result is held back until you trigger your output. Try this instead:

```
header('Location: '.$filename);
ob_end_flush();
exit();
```

Regards,
Mario

Answer (score 1):

The line with

```
die('Command '.$filename);
```

would probably be the culprit. If the `die` (or `exit`) functions (or actually language constructs) take a string as a parameter, it is printed out on the other side before halting. PHP doesn't like you trying to output anything if you are sending headers.

If you are using a reasonably new PHP (>= 4.3.0 iirc), you can use integers 0..255 to mark exit conditions (if you want to), which will not be printed.

Comment: in fact this was just added for debugging, with or without text on exit, it doesn't work.

Comment: For deliberate termination of a script, I use `exit;` alone, as it does not require a parameter or parentheses. I use `die('some error');` for debugging so it's always obvious which code should stay in production.

Answer (score 1):

When you send a redirect, PHP puts the values in the HTTP Response header. The body follows the header. Therefore, if you echo/print any kind of value before using the Header function, it fails, since the Response Headers are already out. Try the same script before printing any text and it will work.

**Normal HTTP Response**

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 12 Jan 2011 18:40:22 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.14
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

[Body of the message]

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 12 Jan 2011 18:40:22 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.14
Location: **profile.php**
Content-Type: text/html

Answer (score 0):

from my experience you can't send any content when you're doing redirect. So I'd guess your problem is the die() parameter.

I can't find this in documentation right now but try dying() it without a parameter or just use exit; I bet it will work.

Comment: nope,, sorry I removed the parameter,  like i told henrik, exit() die() with or without text. The same code works when it's just a link, not if a form was submitted.

Answer (score 0):

```
   header('Location: '.$filename);
flush(); //Try to force server to send header before script die
   die('Command '.$filename);
```

I had the same problem:
script:
header('Location: ...');
die();

Script before sending headers received some data via POST, and if data new make changes to DB.
It is curious, when POST data small and little changes to DB redirect WORK, when POST data bigger and a lot of changes to DB redirect DON'T WORK.
Using flush() after header() solve my problem.

PHP Version 5.2.17
Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)

On my opinion, it looks like server push headers to buffer and dies before sending the buffer content to user, and that is why flush() helped.

If flush does not working, see comments about output buffering settings and zlib.compression:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php